# How should I write functional tests for actions that are supposed to interact with a database with Mocha in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm using Mocha, and am attempting to use it in a functional test.

Here's my code:

```
  test "should post create" do
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    UserSession.create(user)
    recipe_attributes = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:recipe)
    Recipes::Recipe.any_instance.expects(:save)
    post(:create, {'recipes_recipe' => recipe_attributes})
    assert_response(302)
    assert_not_nil(assigns(:recipe))
  end
```

The code fails at `assert_response(302)` stating the response was `200`. When I remove the line:

```
    Recipes::Recipe.any_instance.expects(:save)
```

The test passes.

Here is the `create` action:

```
def create
  @recipe = Recipe.new(params[:recipes_recipe])

  photo_keys = params.keys.select{|k|k.match(/^photo/)}
  @photos = []
  photo_keys.each do |photo_key|
    @photos << Photo.new(params[photo_key])
  end

  @recipe.tags = Tag.parse(params[:tags])

  @recipe.author = current_user

  photos_valid = !@photos.empty? ? @photos.all?{|photo|photo.save} : true

  puts photos_valid.inspect

  if @recipe.save && photos_valid
    unless @photos.empty?
      @photos.each do |photo|
        photo.recipe_id = @recipe.id
        photo.save
      end
    end
    flash[:notice] = 'Recipe was successfully created.'
    redirect_to recipe_url(@recipe.slug)
  else
    puts @recipe.save.inspect
    puts @recipe.errors.inspect
    flash[:error] = 'Could not create recipe. '
    flash[:error] += 'Please correct any mistakes below.'
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

When I put a `puts Recipes::Recipe.all.inspect` in the `else` clause, the list is empty, which I guess is how it should work, because the point of Mocha is to not touch the database to make tests faster.

So, my question is, how should I go about testing in this situation? Is this line enough to ensure that the `create` action is working as it should?

```
Recipes::Recipe.any_instance.expects(:save)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I came up with:

```
  test "should post create" do
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    UserSession.create(user)

    recipe_attributes = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:recipe)

    Recipes::Recipe.any_instance.expects(:save).returns(true)
    Recipes::RecipesController.any_instance.expects(:recipe_url).once.returns('')

    post(:create, {:recipes_recipe => recipe_attributes})

    assert_response(302)
    assert_not_nil(assigns(:recipe))
  end
```

I basically make the save method return true, and just assume that the instance is valid, and so this test case is for all cases where the instance is valid, and tests for the behavior in that case. I'm pretty sure the model can just be tested unit tests, and there's no need to test the models in functional tests. So, I use .returns('') on .expects(:recipe_url) just so recipe_url does not return an error. As long as it is being called, then the controller should be working as expected in all scenarios where the instance is assumed to be valid.